# $.ajax() accessing to the sent values in done()

Tags: jquery, ajax

Imagine this:

```
$('#blah').on('click', function(){
    var cat_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        // stuff...
        data: {cat_id: cat_id}, // <--------------------
        // stuff...
    }).done(function(){
        alert(cat_id); // <-------------------- not defined...
    });
});
```

As you know, jQuery has deprecated the previous usage type of `$.ajax` and the new pattern looks like above, in the above code in the `done()` function, how I could access `cat_id`?
in the done() function `$(this)` is not recognized anymore and `cat_id` neither ...

Before jQuery introduced `done()`, we could easily accessed to the sent data because we were using `success:` and there we could still access the sent data via ajax function.

Comment: you can store the cat_id in ($this).data("catId") and then access it easily.. so you can easily handle multiple events accordingly

Comment: @KD would you please post your code as answer to this question? thanks

Comment: i don't think ..`success()` callback is depricated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you example you can still access cat_id in the done function, as it is still in scope. If you need access to $(this) you need to bind it to the done callback like this:

```
$('#blah').on('click', function(){
    var cat_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        // stuff...
        data: {cat_id: cat_id}, // <--------------------
        // stuff...
    }).done(function(){
        alert(cat_id); // alerts 'blah'
        alert($(this).attr('id')); // also alerts 'blah'
    }.bind(this)); // NOTICE THIS
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, working, answer would get accepted if I had not flagged one yet

Answer (score 1):

I could not replicate the behaviour you wrote about, however if you need to access jQuery(this) in the done function you can do something like this:

```
$('#blah').on('click', function(){
    var cat_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var $self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        // stuff...
        data: {cat_id: cat_id}, 
        // stuff...
    }).done(function(){
        alert($self.attr('id')); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a workaround though, but you can do it like this...

Store the cat_id in **$(this).data("catId")** and then access it easily.. 
so you can easily handle multiple events accordingly.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the power of closures, this should work :

```
var cat_id = $(this).attr('id');
var done_handler = function(){
        alert(cat_id);
};
    $.ajax({
        // stuff...
        data: {cat_id: cat_id}, // <--------------------
        // stuff...
    }).done(done_handler);
```